# Mocking Mule Variables Using JUnit

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mule, mule-studio

For the following Mule flow, how would I mock the random_var variable using JUnit?

```
<flow name="FLOW1" doc:name="FLOW1">
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="${random_var} == 'true'">
            <logger message="Random var is True" level="DEBUG" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <logger message="Random var is False" level="DEBUG" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</flow>
```

Comment: How are you invoking this flow in your Testing?

Comment: @user1760178, using a VM Endpoint. The flow is obviously incomplete, because it doesn't contain any endpoints. My question is more about assigning a value to "random_var" from JUnit.

Answer (score 0):

I think first of all you would need a vm-endpoint in order to be able to call this test from within a functional test.

Further you should have a look at:
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Functional+Testing

For programmatically invoking vm-endpoints using unit test.
It also describes how to pass a payload to it.

The Func-Test also will use a separated set of config file so you can define a separated configuration for the flow, which seems to be the thing that you are looking for.
Where would you normally define this variable? In you application-config.xml?
The func test allow running the flow with a test config (you can obviously use the same config for test and running the flow in the Mule app server)

Sebastian

Comment: I would define this variable in a Spring ".properties" file.